# Jasper Print page different from the contens in the screen

Tags: java, printing, jasper-reports, jtextarea, jtextpane

our Java project has a problem and I need your advice:

We have a JTextPane component which is customized to support pagination. The component's content must be printed using JasperReport. The problem is: although we have used the same font's name, size, style, and page's height and width for the JTextPane and JasperReport, but the print-page is always different from the contents in the screen, typically a few characters are not aligned properly between the 2 devices (print-page and screen-page); as a result the content may be displayed in only 1 screen-page but will be printed into 2 pages.

EDIT:

[image: One example]

There is a `JTextarea` (First text) with the same Font as the Jasper print (Second text) (DejaVu Serif 10), but the length of the texts are different.

The question is: I need the same text length on the screen and on the Jasper Print, but i dont know how to do that. For example I have a `JTextarea` with a fix width of pixel maybe 700. The jasper textfield has also a width of 700 pixel. Now I expect the text on the screen and on jasper ist exactly the same if I configure the same font, but there are different. What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you please attach any sample screen..

Comment: @Peter What is your question?

Comment: i have edited my post

Comment: Two ideas : could the problem come from borders ? Otherwise, maybe you could calculate the optimal font size in Jasper Print. You can get the current text width by `getPreferredSize().width`. If this result is longer in Jasper Print than JTextArea, you reduce Jasper Print font size.